# Tab view application in cocoa crashing

Tags: cocoa, tabitem, tabview

I am creating a tab view app in cocoa like a web browser app:

1. I am loading my first tab with subview web View Controller ( having a webview and a text field) in the awakefromnib method.
2. There is another tab item with "+" label. When I click on it the didTabSelected delegate method is called.
3. In it I creating a new tab item and adding the subview of webViewController class ( having a webview and a text field).
4. In the textfield of webViewController.xib i am setting its action to a IBAction which is losading the web view.

Issues:

1. When I am running the application the textfield action is caliing automatically without pressing enter, even when i am switching between the tabs.
2. My app is crasing when i amswitching between the tabs.

thanks

i am getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: With what error message?

Answer (score 1):

Are  you getting an error like EXEC_BAD_ACCESS or unrecognized selector? For the former something is null or overreleased and that is the problem. For the latter, you might be trying to call a method that doesn't exist.